# if else. javascript. display result in textbox

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I only know a little Java and PHP. I want to know, is it possible that, for example, "IF radiobutton1 AND Radiobutton2 AND radiobutton3 AND radiobutton4 is click Then the Value of the textbox1 is 10. else IF radiobutton1 AND Radiobutton2 AND radiobutton5 AND radiobutton6 is click then the value of textbox2 is 20"? I want to do something like this.

My code is here and the output:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Belle</title>
<script  language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body style="margin: 0; border: 0;">

 <table border=0 align="center">
    <th colspan="3"><h2><font color="black"



<th>


</font></h2></th>


    <tr><td>
    <table border="0" bordercolorlight="#FFFF99">

        <th align="center" colspan="3" bgcolor="black"><font color="white">FIRST</font></th>
            <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
                <tr>
                <td><input type="radio" name="flight" value="tnternational">International</td >
                <td><input type="radio" name="flight" value="Domestic">Domestic</td >
                </tr>
            <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>

        <th align="center" colspan="3" bgcolor="black"><font color="white">SECOND</font></th>
        <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Type:</td>
            <form action="javascript:return true;" name="form1"> 
            <td><input type="radio" name="group1" value="opt1" id="opt1" onclick="show()"><label for="opt1">One Way</label></td>            
            <td><input type="radio" name="group1" value="opt2" id="opt2" onclick="show()"><label for="opt2">Round Trip</label></td>
        </tr>       
        <tr>
            <td>Insurance:</td>
            <td><input type="radio" id="m1" name="insurance" value='250'/>Yes</td>
            <td><input type="radio" id="m2" name="insurance" value='0'/>No</td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>

        <th align="center" colspan="3" bgcolor="black"><font color="white">THIRD</font></th>
        <tr><td>&nbsp;<td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></td><td >
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><center>One</center></td>
            <td><center>Two</center></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
            B:</br></br></br></br></br></br>
            S1: </br></br></br></br>
            S2:</br></br>
            H: </br></br>
            I:</br></br>
            </td>
            <td>
            <input type="radio" value="0" name="bgto">None<br/>
            <input type="radio" value="201.60" name="bgto">10kg<br/>
            <input type="radio" value="201.60" name="bgto">15kg<br/>
            <input type="radio" value="336.00" name="bgto">20kg<br/>
            <input type="radio" value="672.00" name="bgto">30kg<br/>
            <input type="radio" value="1232.00" name="bgto">45kg<br/>
            <input type="radio" value="0" name="ssto">None<br/>
            <input type="radio" value="257.60" name="ssto">Premium<br/>
            <input type="radio" value="145.60" name="ssto">Standard<br/>
            <input type="radio" value="1120.00" name="seto">Yes<br/>
            <input type="radio" value="0" name="seto">No<br/>
            <input type="radio" value="50" name="hmto">Yes<br/>
            <input type="radio" value="50" name="hmto">No<br/>
            <input type="radio" value="336" name="infto">Yes<br/>
            <input type="radio" value="0" name="infto">No<br/>
            </td>


            <td><div id="from"> 
            <input type="radio" value="opt2" name="bgfrom">None<br/>
            <input type="radio" value="opt2" name="bgfrom">10kg<br/>
            <input type="radio" value="opt2" name="bgfrom">15kg<br/>
            <input type="radio" value="opt2" name="bgfrom">20kg<br/>
            <input type="radio" value="opt2" name="bgfrom">30kg<br/>
            <input type="radio" value="opt2" name="bgfrom">45kg<br/>
            <input type="radio" value="opt2" name="ssfrom">None<br/>
            <input type="radio" value="opt2" name="ssfrom">Premium<br/>
            <input type="radio" value="opt2" name="ssfrom">Standard<br/>
            <input type="radio" value="opt2" name="ssfrom">Stan-Plus<br/>
            <input type="radio" value="opt2" name="sefrom">Yes<br/>
            <input type="radio" value="opt2" name="sefrom">No<br/>
            <input type="radio" value="opt2" name="hmfrom">Yes<br/>
            <input type="radio" value="opt2" name="hmfrom">No<br/>
            <input type="radio" value="opt2" name="inffrom">Yes<br/>
            <input type="radio" value="opt2" name="inffrom">No<br/>
            </div></td>
        </tr>
        </td></form>
    </table>
    <br/>   

    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
    <td>
    <table border="0" bordercolorlight="BLACK">
    <th align="center" colspan="2" bgcolor="bLACK"><font color="white">CALCULATE</font></th>

    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <form name="frmMain">
    <tr><td>F: </td><td><input type="text" name="txtNumberA" value="0"> </td></tr>
    <tr><td>I:  </td><td><input type="text" id="txtNumberB" name="txtNumberB" value=""> </td></tr>
    <tr><td>B:   </td><td><input type="text" id="txtNumberD" name="txtNumberD" value=""> </td></tr>
    <tr><td>S1:  </td><td><input type="text" id="txtNumberE" name="txtNumberE" value=""> </td></tr>
    <tr><td>S2:  </td><td><input type="text" id="txtNumberF" name="txtNumberF" value=""> </td></tr>
    <tr><td>H:  </td><td><input type="text" id="txtNumberG" name="txtNumberG" value=""> </td></tr>
    <tr><td>I:   </td><td><input type="text" id="txtNumberH" name="txtNumberH" value=""> </td></tr>
    <tr><td>TOTAL:</td><td><input type="text" name="txtNumberC" value=""> </td></tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="button" name="btnSum" value="TOTAL" OnClick="fncSum();"></td>
    <td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
    </form>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            (function($)
            {
                $(function() 
                {
                    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(e)
                    {
                        value = $("input[name=insurance]:checked").val();
                        $('#txtNumberB').val(value);
                    });
                });
            })(jQuery);
            </script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            (function($)
            {
                $(function() 
                {
                    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(e)
                    {
                        value = $("input[name=bgto]:checked").val();
                        $('#txtNumberD').val(value);
                    });
                });
            })(jQuery);
            </script>

            <script type="text/javascript">
            (function($)
            {
                $(function() 
                {
                    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(e)
                    {
                        value = $("input[name=ssto]:checked").val();
                        $('#txtNumberE').val(value);
                    });
                });
            })(jQuery);
            </script>

            <script type="text/javascript">
            (function($)
            {
                $(function() 
                {
                    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(e)
                    {
                        value = $("input[name=seto]:checked").val();
                        $('#txtNumberF').val(value);
                    });
                });
            })(jQuery);
            </script>

            <script type="text/javascript">
            (function($)
            {
                $(function() 
                {
                    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(e)
                    {
                        value = $("input[name=hmto]:checked").val();
                        $('#txtNumberG').val(value);
                    });
                });
            })(jQuery);
            </script>

            <script type="text/javascript">
            (function($)
            {
                $(function() 
                {
                    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(e)
                    {
                        value = $("input[name=infto]:checked").val();
                        $('#txtNumberH').val(value);
                    });
                });
            })(jQuery);
            </script>       
    <script>
        var dl = document.getElementById('from'); 
        dl.style.visibility = 'hidden'; 
        function show() 
        { 
            for (var i=0; i < document.form1.group1.length; i++) 
                { 
                if (document.form1.group1[i].checked) 
                    { 
                    var radio = document.form1.group1[i].value; 
                    } 
                } 
                if (radio == 'opt2') 
                    { 
                        dl.style.visibility = 'visible'; 
                    }
                else 
                    { 
                        dl.style.visibility = 'hidden'; 
                    } 
        } 
    </script> 


    <script>
        function calculate_total(className, total_text)
        {
            var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
            var total = 0;
            for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i)
            {
                if(elements[i].className == className)
                {
                    total += parseInt(elements[i].value);
                }
            }
            document.getElementById(total_text).innerHTML = "Total: " + total;
        }
    </script> 

        <script>
        function fncSum()
        {
            if(isNaN(document.frmMain.txtNumberA.value) || document.frmMain.txtNumberA.value == "")
            {
            alert('(Number A)Please input Number only.');
            document.frmMain.txtNumberA.focus();
            return;
            }

            if(isNaN(document.frmMain.txtNumberB.value) || document.frmMain.txtNumberB.value == "")
            {
            alert('(Number B)Please input Number only.');
            document.frmMain.txtNumberB.focus();
            return;
            }
            if(isNaN(document.frmMain.txtNumberD.value) || document.frmMain.txtNumberD.value == "")
            {
            alert('(Number D)Please input Number only.');
            document.frmMain.txtNumberD.focus();
            return;
            }
            if(isNaN(document.frmMain.txtNumberE.value) || document.frmMain.txtNumberE.value == "")
            {
            alert('(Number E)Please input Number only.');
            document.frmMain.txtNumberE.focus();
            return;
            }
            if(isNaN(document.frmMain.txtNumberF.value) || document.frmMain.txtNumberF.value == "")
            {
            alert('(Number F)Please input Number only.');
            document.frmMain.txtNumberF.focus();
            return;
            }
            if(isNaN(document.frmMain.txtNumberG.value) || document.frmMain.txtNumberG.value == "")
            {
            alert('(Number G)Please input Number only.');
            document.frmMain.txtNumberG.focus();
            return;
            }
            if(isNaN(document.frmMain.txtNumberH.value) || document.frmMain.txtNumberH.value == "")
            {
            alert('(Number H)Please input Number only.');
            document.frmMain.txtNumberH.focus();
            return;
            }

            document.frmMain.txtNumberC.value = parseFloat(document.frmMain.txtNumberA.value) + 
                                                parseFloat(document.frmMain.txtNumberB.value) +
                                                parseFloat(document.frmMain.txtNumberD.value) +
                                                parseFloat(document.frmMain.txtNumberE.value) +
                                                parseFloat(document.frmMain.txtNumberF.value) +
                                                parseFloat(document.frmMain.txtNumberG.value) +
                                                parseFloat(document.frmMain.txtNumberH.value);
        }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The best approach for me is: 1st. read documentation; 2nd. try some code; without these any answer will be a nonsense...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Via jQuery

```
$('button').bind('click',function(){
    if($('#a').is(':checked')&& $('#c').is(':checked')){
        $('input').val('Sometext');
    }
});
```

Here is fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Goodluck/eay96/
I don't know what is automatic in your case, but you can make it onchange as well:

```
$('.cb').change(function(){
    if($('#a').is(':checked')&& $('#c').is(':checked')){
        $('input').val('Sometext');
    }
});
```

And the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Goodluck/eay96/1/

Comment: thank you. still working on it. i want to diplay it automatic. but ill try yours, (with a button) :) - sorry i have no background about javascript or jquery :(

Answer (score 1):

This javascript sample could be a good start:

```
if (document.forms['myForm'].elements["radio1"].checked && 
    document.forms['myForm'].elements["radio2"].checked && 
    document.forms['myForm'].elements["radio5"].checked
   )
{
    document.forms['myForm'].elements["textbox2"].value = 10;

} else if (document.forms['myForm'].elements["radio3"].checked && 
    document.forms['myForm'].elements["radio4"].checked && 
    document.forms['myForm'].elements["radio7"].checked
   )
{
    document.forms['myForm'].elements["textbox2"].value = 20;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. still working on it :) sorry i have no background about javascript :(

Comment: It's almost like java, which you know a little about. This site has some basics that will help you start learning and then my sample above for sure will make sense: http://www.w3schools.com/js/

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script  language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table border="0" bordercolorlight="#FFFF99">
<form name="frmMain">
    <th align="center" colspan="3" bgcolor="black"><font color="white">FIRST</font></th>
    <tr><td colspan="3"><center><input type="radio" name="flight" value="International" class="flight" id="intl">International</td ></tr>

    <th align="center" colspan="3" bgcolor="black"><font color="white">SECOND</font></th>
    <tr><td>Type:</td>
        <td colspan="2"><center><input type="radio" name="group1" value="opt1" id="opt1" onclick="show()" class="flight"><label for="opt1">One Way</label></td>            
    </tr>       
    <tr><td>I:</td>
        <td colspan="2"><center><input type="radio" id="m1" name="insurance" value='0' class="flight"/>Yes
        <input type="radio" id="m2" name="insurance" value='0' class="flight"/>No</td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>I:</td><td><input type="text" id="txtNumberB" name="txtNumberB" value="0" class="flight"> </td></tr>

<script>
$('.flight').change(function(){
    if($('#intl').is(':checked')&& $('#opt1').is(':checked')&& $('#m1').is(':checked'))
        {
            document.frmMain.txtNumberB.value = 250.00;
        }
    if($('#intl').is(':checked')&& $('#opt1').is(':checked')&& $('#m2').is(':checked'))
        {
            document.frmMain.txtNumberB.value = 0.00;
        }
        });
</script>
</html>
```

like this :) :) thank youu.